# How can I measure TVS diode for Seagate Momentus 7200.3?

Tags: hard-drive

I hope the TVS diode (or something like this) of my HDD's PCB is gone, so I could fix this HDD easily, but I don't know where it is. Can you tell me how to measure it?

I [read this](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Barracuda-XT-Barracuda-and/Need-PCB-Replacement-for-Momentus-7200-3-ST9320421ASG/m-p/40296) but I didn't understand, why 3 pins? I'm measuring the circuit resistance since I'm not measuring specifically the diode so I understand that if it's broken the resistance could be different than infinite, so how much should be the resistance?

My broken hdd history is here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/242014/is-my-hdd-dead-forever

Comment: Measuring component values in circuit can be difficult, especially if you don't have the schematics to study, more so if you aren't really sure of what you are looking for. You might have better luck if this question is moved to electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link to the SATA pinout of the forum page you linked to, pins 7,8,9 are all +5V, so that is just for one end of the diode. Presumably the other end is connected to pins 4/5/6 or 10/11/12 and you could replace it with a TVS diode of the same physical size and a rated voltage **above** 5V. Given that 5V ICs usually work at least 0.5V above or below the 5V spec, and the 5% tolerance of the TVS threshold, you should be safe with a 6.8V TVS diode. They are usually unipolar so getting it the right way round is important (otherwise you are reducing the 5V rail to 0.7V).

You can't measure the breakdown voltage of a TVS diode or zener using the resistance range of a meter. They are deliberately non-linear devices, so the resistance you measure depends on the voltage applied. The only way to measure the breakdown voltage with a meter would be to isolate the (working!) device, use a current limited adjustable voltage supply set to 1mA, increase the voltage until 1mA flows, then measure the voltage across the device. For smaller devices rated less than 5 watts, you probably need to use the pulsed version of this method to avoid heating the device up too much.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Please help me on this: if the TVS was defective shouldn't it be short-circuited, and couldn't I verify this by measuring the resistance? I don't care about the hdd, I just want the data back and I don't think I have the appropriate tools to weld such small components, so my idea was to find out if this component is defective and extract it or short-circuit it (depending on what is going to make the hdd work, I don't know) just to get the data.

Comment: If the TVS is defective, the melted silicon could produce any resistance; I wouldn't say it must measure as a short. You need to remove it rather than short it out. You'd need access to a soldering iron to heat the junctions with the board. Solder goes underneath the component so you can't use a knife to cut the solder away at the ends, and in any case you risk cutting the tracks, they are only a thin layer.